# Check if WebView url is loaded

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a webview component embedded in my react-native page. My goal is to have a skeleton Placeholder displayed while the webview component's url is fully loaded. I was wondering if there's an easy way to check/track/indicate when the loading of the url is completed, that way when it's loading I can display the SkeletonPlaceholder.
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256826/react-native-webview-loading-indicator